# How do I create a date picker in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any standard way tkinter apps allow the user to choose a date?

Comment: Impropable, as tkinter is very minimalistic. If you want something fancy without building it yourself, your best bet is one of the larger, batteries-included GUI toolkits (I recommend Qt).

Comment: +1 totally reasonable question. This is the kind of UI thing that should be standardized within a toolkit. Surprised tk doesn't offer it.

Answer (score 31):

In case anyone still needs this - here's a simple code to create a Calendar and DateEntry widget using tkcalendar package.

> `pip install tkcalendar` *(for installing the package)*

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

def example1():
    def print_sel():
        print(cal.selection_get())

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    cal = Calendar(top,
                   font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',
                   cursor="hand1", year=2018, month=2, day=5)
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()

def example2():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Choose date').pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    cal = DateEntry(top, width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')

ttk.Button(root, text='Calendar', command=example1).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='DateEntry', command=example2).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 12):

Not as far as I could find. For anyone who wants to do this in the future:

I used [tkSimpleDialog](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) and [ttkcalendar.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/ttk-gsoc/samples/ttkcalendar.py) (with modifications from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476647/875832) SO post) to make a [CalendarDialog](https://github.com/moshekaplan/tkinter_components/blob/master/CalendarDialog/CalendarDialog.py). The modified versions of the three files are available on my [github](https://github.com/moshekaplan/tkinter_components/tree/master/CalendarDialog).

Below is the code in my [CalendarDialog.py](https://github.com/moshekaplan/tkinter_components/blob/master/CalendarDialog/CalendarDialog.py):

```
import Tkinter

import ttkcalendar
import tkSimpleDialog

class CalendarDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    """Dialog box that displays a calendar and returns the selected date"""
    def body(self, master):
        self.calendar = ttkcalendar.Calendar(master)
        self.calendar.pack()

    def apply(self):
        self.result = self.calendar.selection

# Demo code:
def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.wm_title("CalendarDialog Demo")

    def onclick():
        cd = CalendarDialog(root)
        print cd.result

    button = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Click me to see a calendar!", command=onclick)
    button.pack()
    root.update()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Heh, the python source file you linked doesn't actually HAVE those modifications in it - ran into a stumbling block until I realized it had to be modified to get it to play nice with an actual Tkinter app :P

Comment: Yeah, that's why I linked to the patched versions on my github as well.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, thanks. I just assumed the links all went to the same place because I didn't read them close enough to see they weren't all github :P

Answer (score 11):

Try with the following:

```
from tkinter import *

from tkcalendar import Calendar,DateEntry

root = Tk()

cal = DateEntry(root,width=30,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=2010)

cal.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

where `tkcalendar` library should be downloaded and installed through `pip install tkcalender` command.

Answer (score 6):

The answers here provide most of what you asked for, but I felt none of them were completely satisfying. As a Tkinter newbie, I needed more hand-holding. My complaints:

1. Assuming I want the calendar to default to a 2012 date rather than today's date,
2. Not returning the result as a variable for future use,
3. An unnecessary top layer menu before getting to the calendar, and
4. Not cleaning up the windows and exiting mainloop after a selection has been made.

So with gratitude to the previous answers which helped me immensely, here's my version.

```
def get_date():
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

    def cal_done():
        top.withdraw()
        root.quit()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw() # keep the root window from appearing

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    cal = Calendar(top,
                   font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',
                   cursor="hand1")
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=cal_done).pack()

    selected_date = None
    root.mainloop()
    return cal.selection_get()

selection = get_date()
print(selection)
```

Comment: Interesting how `cal_done` is defined within `get_date` function. I've only seen it done within classes and mainline before.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Best answer IMO. The only think I would change is in the kill command use `top.destroy()` and `root.destroy()`. This will allow you to use the Spyder IDE without issues when you make the selection. Otherwise you have to keep creating new terminals.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can get it from the user as a datetime element from a formatted string..

Example:

```
import datetime

userdatestring = '2013-05-10'
thedate = datetime.datetime.strptime(userdatestring, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Check out http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior. It's handy, although not the most user friendly way of getting a date.

Answer (score 4):

This is how we code a python datepicker in tkinter.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Author: Rambarun Komaljeet
# License: Freeware
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
import time
from tkinter import ttk


class MyDatePicker(tk.Toplevel):
    """
    Description:
        A tkinter GUI date picker.
    """

    def __init__(self, widget=None, format_str=None):
        """
        :param widget: widget of parent instance.

        :param format_str: print format in which to display date.
        :type format_str: string

        Example::
            a = MyDatePicker(self, widget=self.parent widget,
                             format_str='%02d-%s-%s')
        """

        super().__init__()
        self.widget = widget
        self.str_format = format_str

        self.title("Date Picker")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.geometry("+630+390")

        self.init_frames()
        self.init_needed_vars()
        self.init_month_year_labels()
        self.init_buttons()
        self.space_between_widgets()
        self.fill_days()
        self.make_calendar()

    def init_frames(self):
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame1.pack()

        self.frame_days = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_days.pack()

    def init_needed_vars(self):
        self.month_names = tuple(calendar.month_name)
        self.day_names = tuple(calendar.day_abbr)
        self.year = time.strftime("%Y")
        self.month = time.strftime("%B")

    def init_month_year_labels(self):
        self.year_str_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.month_str_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.year_str_var.set(self.year)
        self.year_lbl = tk.Label(self.frame1, textvariable=self.year_str_var,
                                 width=3)
        self.year_lbl.grid(row=0, column=5)

        self.month_str_var.set(self.month)
        self.month_lbl = tk.Label(self.frame1, textvariable=self.month_str_var,
                                  width=8)
        self.month_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def init_buttons(self):
        self.left_yr = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="←", width=5,
                                  command=self.prev_year)
        self.left_yr.grid(row=0, column=4)

        self.right_yr = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="→", width=5,
                                   command=self.next_year)
        self.right_yr.grid(row=0, column=6)

        self.left_mon = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="←", width=5,
                                   command=self.prev_month)
        self.left_mon.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.right_mon = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="→", width=5,
                                    command=self.next_month)
        self.right_mon.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def space_between_widgets(self):
        self.frame1.grid_columnconfigure(3, minsize=40)

    def prev_year(self):
        self.prev_yr = int(self.year_str_var.get()) - 1
        self.year_str_var.set(self.prev_yr)

        self.make_calendar()

    def next_year(self):
        self.next_yr = int(self.year_str_var.get()) + 1
        self.year_str_var.set(self.next_yr)

        self.make_calendar()

    def prev_month(self):
        index_current_month = self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get())
        index_prev_month = index_current_month - 1

        #  index 0 is empty string, use index 12 instead,
        # which is index of December.
        if index_prev_month == 0:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[12])
        else:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[index_current_month - 1])

        self.make_calendar()

    def next_month(self):
        index_current_month = self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get())

        try:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[index_current_month + 1])
        except IndexError:
            #  index 13 does not exist, use index 1 instead, which is January.
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[1])

        self.make_calendar()

    def fill_days(self):
        col = 0
        #  Creates days label
        for day in self.day_names:
            self.lbl_day = tk.Label(self.frame_days, text=day)
            self.lbl_day.grid(row=0, column=col)
            col += 1

    def make_calendar(self):
        #  Delete date buttons if already present.
        #  Each button must have its own instance attribute for this to work.
        try:
            for dates in self.m_cal:
                for date in dates:
                    if date == 0:
                        continue

                    self.delete_buttons(date)

        except AttributeError:
            pass

        year = int(self.year_str_var.get())
        month = self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get())
        self.m_cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)

        #  build dates buttons.
        for dates in self.m_cal:
            row = self.m_cal.index(dates) + 1
            for date in dates:
                col = dates.index(date)

                if date == 0:
                    continue

                self.make_button(str(date), str(row), str(col))

    def make_button(self, date, row, column):
        """
        Description:
            Build a date button.

        :param date: date.
        :type date: string

        :param row: row number.
        :type row: string

        :param column: column number.
        :type column: string
        """
        exec(
            "self.btn_" + date + " = ttk.Button(self.frame_days, text=" + date
            + ", width=5)\n"
            "self.btn_" + date + ".grid(row=" + row + " , column=" + column
            + ")\n"
            "self.btn_" + date + ".bind(\"<Button-1>\", self.get_date)"
        )

    def delete_buttons(self, date):
        """
        Description:
            Delete a date button.

        :param date: date.
        :type: string
        """
        exec(
            "self.btn_" + str(date) + ".destroy()"
        )

    def get_date(self, clicked=None):
        """
        Description:
            Get the date from the calendar on button click.

        :param clicked: button clicked event.
        :type clicked: tkinter event
        """

        clicked_button = clicked.widget
        year = self.year_str_var.get()
        month = self.month_str_var.get()
        date = clicked_button['text']

        self.full_date = self.str_format % (date, month, year)
        print(self.full_date)
        #  Replace with parent 'widget' of your choice.
        try:
            self.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.widget.insert(0, self.full_date)
        except AttributeError:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def application():
        MyDatePicker(format_str='%02d-%s-%s')

    root = tk.Tk()
    btn = tk.Button(root, text="test", command=application)
    btn.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Error message please.Alsp note that is python 3 code.

Comment: In fact I'm using python 2. The error starts not findind "super()".

Answer (score 1):

You should install the tkcalendar module. Use pip3 for this:

`pip3 install tkcalendar`

After the install you can import the module in your code.

Use **this**:

```
from tkcalendar import Calendar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add another library and you are happy with a very simple Spinbox that accepts iso dates with a little up and down arrow, looking like this:

[image: Screenshot of Spinbox]

You can use this code:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from tkinter import Spinbox, StringVar, Event

_PLUS_ONE_DAY = timedelta(days=1)
_MINUS_ONE_DAY = timedelta(days=-1)


class DatePicker(Spinbox):
    def __init__(self, master=None, initial: date = None, **kw):
        if initial is None:
            initial = date.today()
        self.date = initial
        self.string_var = StringVar(master, "1")
        super().__init__(master, textvariable=self.string_var, from_=0, to=10000, **kw)

        self.string_var.set(initial.isoformat())
        self.config(command=self._check_value_change)
        self.string_var.trace_add("write", self._on_string_var_change)
        self.bind('<Return>', self._on_enter_pressed)

    def _on_enter_pressed(self, event: Event):
        self.string_var.set(self.date.isoformat())
        self.winfo_toplevel().focus_set()

    def _on_string_var_change(self, s0: str, s1: str, s2: str):
        try:
            year, month, day = self.string_var.get().split("-")
            self.date = date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
        except ValueError:
            return

    def _check_value_change(self):
        new_value = self.get()
        if new_value == str(self.date.year - 1):
            self.date += _MINUS_ONE_DAY
        elif new_value == str(self.date.year + 1):
            self.date += _PLUS_ONE_DAY

        self.string_var.set(self.date.isoformat())
```

While the code is relatively short, its not particularly pretty, as it tricks a `Spinbox` to behave like an input method for dates. Call `date_picker.date` to get the currently held date value.

Please note that changing the format is not straight forward. Leave a comment if you are interested in a version that supports other formats