# Python Calendar Widget

Tags: python, calendar, tkinter

I found [this](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/ttk-gsoc/samples/ttkcalendar.py) Python calendar widget though [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443786/how-do-i-create-a-date-picker-in-tkinter). I am trying to print out the date that user selected on the calendar. What i tried is something like this

```
mycalendar=Calendar()
print mycalendar.selection()
```

I know this small piece of code alone doesn't make things clear. "Calendar" is a class and selection(self) is a function inside Calendar class with return value. For clear understanding please see the link i provided above as the code is too long to post here.

My problem is once i run the script, instead of giving me the return number from function, it give me this error message "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable". Is there any way to get the user selected date on the calendar to printed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the class you posted, the `_pressed` function is called the after user clicks the mouse inside the calendar window.

To print the date, add `print self.selection` after the following code block:

```
    # update and then show selection
    text = '%02d' % text
    self._selection = (text, item, column)
    self._show_selection(text, bbox)

    print self.selection  # print the date selected to the console
```