# Python QtGui Calendar Widget Call button

Tags: python, calendar, widget, qwidget, qtgui

I am using a calendar widget for Python. And I need to call the widget when a button is clicked.
The situation is that I cannot find what is the method in the calendar class that displays the widget itself.
The calendar class was taken from here:
http://www.eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Calendar_Date%20picker.html

Here are my imports:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
import requests #needs to be installed
import pymysql #needs to be installed
import csv 
import win32com.client #needs to be installed
from calendar import Calendar
import datetime
```

Here is the button creation:

```
# Calendar Buttons
calBut=ttk.Button(f2, width=4, text="Cal",       command=Calendar.what_method?).grid(column=3,row=1, sticky=W)
```

As far as I know, I can just set the command of the button to call the widget display method located in the calendar class.
How to get the method that displays the calendar widget each time my button is clicked? None of the ones showing are displaying the widget.

Using Python 3.3.5
Spider
WinPython 3.3.5

****EDIT****

The program has tabs and the f2 indicates the tab where the button will be.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
import requests #needs to be installed
import pymysql #needs to be installed
import csv 
import win32com.client #needs to be installed
import datetime
from calendar import Calendar
import calendar


#################################
# Create Button Click Calendar

 def callback():
    root2=Toplevel(f2)
    ttkcal = Calendar(root2,firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)
    ttkcal.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
    root2.update()
    root2.minsize(root2.winfo_reqwidth(), root2.winfo_reqheight())



 # Calendar Buttons

 b=ttk.Button(f2, width=4, text="Cal", command=callback).grid(column=3,row=1, sticky=W)
```

When I press the button, it opens the calendar window, but it is empty. And the console gives me error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'firstweekday
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so easy. The problem is that you mix the two GUI libraries. Therefore it is necessary two main event loops (at least): one for `Tkinter` code and one for `PyQt` code. 
One way to do what you want - using `subprocess` and `threading` modules to run `calendar.py` in different thread. Example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import subprocess
import threading

master = Tk()

def callback():
    subprocess.call('python calendar.py')


b=ttk.Button(master, width=4, text="Cal", command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=callback).start()).grid(column=3,row=1, sticky=W)


mainloop()
```

Another way - creating Qt main event loop inside callback function (dirty solution):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from calendar import Calendar
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

master = Tk()

def callback():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Calendar()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()


b=ttk.Button(master, width=4, text="Cal", command=callback).grid(column=3,row=1, sticky=W)

mainloop()
```

**EDIT: How to call widget.**
First of all, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476647/3489230) answer, and modify your `ttkcalendar.py` as *kalgasnik* suggested. Then try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkcalendar import Calendar
import calendar

master = Tk()

def callback():
    root2=Toplevel(master)
    ttkcal = Calendar(root2,firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)
    ttkcal.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
    root2.update()
    root2.minsize(root2.winfo_reqwidth(), root2.winfo_reqheight())

b=ttk.Button(master, width=4, text="Cal", command=callback).grid(column=3,row=1, sticky=W)

mainloop()
```

**EDIT 2. Solving the problems**
Ok, it seems I found all problems.

1. Actually, you import twice the same module - standard [calendar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html.) module:

   ```
   from calendar import Calendar
   import calendar
   ```

But you do not import the class `Calendar` from  [ttkcalendar](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Demo/tkinter/ttk/ttkcalendar.py) module (Do not forget to change it as described 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476647/3489230)). 
So, import should look like this:

```
import ttkcalendar
import calendar
```

Creating calendar (I changed the code a bit for clarity):

```
ttkcal = ttkcalendar.Calendar(root2,firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)
```

2. In your code, the main window is initialized twice:
   line 15:    `master = Tk()`
   line 960:   `root = Tk()`
   You need to remove the first initialization.
3. You mix `pack()` and `grid()` in the same master window. According the [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), it is a bad idea:

> Warning: Never mix grid and pack in the same master window. Tkinter
>   will happily spend the rest of your  lifetime trying to negotiate a
>   solution that both managers are happy with.  Instead of waiting, kill
>   the application, and take another look at your code.  A common mistake
>   is to use the wrong parent for some of the widgets.

So, instead `nb.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')` you have to write something like this 
`nb.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E))`

Finally, here are links to the fixed code:
`ttkcalendar.py` (already modified, ready to use): 
     https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5e0d973f57e185572df2
Your script with described modifications: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/65cb808dc64e414c0c12

Comment: Thank you NorthCat. But I get this error no matter what option I use. (Clan or dirty)

TclError: bad window path name ".123364520"

Comment: Or if what I do makes no sense, is there a calendar snipet for a calendar for Tkinter?

Comment: @AlvaroMoralesSolis There are several calendar sippets: 1) http://python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=5104#p6544 2) http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Demo/tkinter/ttk/ttkcalendar.py 3) http://pythonical.sourceforge.net/dlgCalendar.py

Comment: Thank you, I am using this one:
http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Demo/tkinter/ttk/ttkcalendar.py
For that snipet, what would be the best way to set the callback to display the widget after button click?
Thank you

Comment: I don't even know how to update this. Does anybody know how to call the widget display at button press?

Comment: @AlvaroMoralesSolis I've updated the answer to include instructions on how to call a widget.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried that, but it is still giving me :  TclError: bad window path name ".118974784"
Any ideas why?

Comment: @AlvaroMoralesSolis When you receive an error? At the time of starting the program?

Comment: Yes, when I run it in Spyder.

Comment: I just found what the issue was. It is the master = Tk() on the code.
The program has tabs. I use tab2 as f2 for the button.
I removed the master = Tk() and the program now runs. However, the button is doing nothing when I press it. 
I updated my question so you can see what I have.
Thank you

Comment: @AlvaroMoralesSolis `master = Tk()` creates the main window, so you can not do without it. Can you show your entire code?

Comment: Ok, the thing is that if I leave the master = Tk() it will give me the window path name error.
The code is quite long. So I added it here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8e23c8e631a3908154bb

In line 1088 you'll see the button. 
Thanks a lot for your patience and help!

Comment: @AlvaroMoralesSolis Can you give a link to your entire code?

Comment: Is the Gist one not working?
 gist.github.com/anonymous/8e23c8e631a3908154bb

Comment: @AlvaroMoralesSolis It seems, I  corrected all the errors, and updated my answer. Try it!

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the delay. Was out of the office. 
I will try it now. 
Just a question. If I install Python 3.4 and run this app with it, will I get problems since this app was created on 3.3.3?

Comment: @AlvaroMoralesSolis I checked my code on Python 3.3.0 and 3.4.1. It works well on both versions. So it should be no problem.

Comment: Awesome! It worked!
You really helped me a lot.
Thank you very much for your time and patience.
For some reason I can't vote up your answer... It gives a -1.