# Make a calendar view for events in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar

So what I'm trying to do is to make a calendar frame, just like the view of google calendar or any other calendar program really, where I can select a day and see the events I have to do on that day and it's time using python tkinter. Currently on my database I have events with date, starting time and ending time. Note that I am using python 3. Can anyone please give me a clue for how to do it or even send a link to a website where it says how to do it. But please, I'm not searching for a date picker just a calendar showing me what thing I should do when. Thank you ;)

Comment: Please refer to [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Either learn tkinter and you will know how to do it, or learn some HTML and CSS and use a Python web framework (such as flask or django, or many others) to build it the web way. There are entire books on both paths, but also documentation in the web.

Comment: `tkinter` has `grid()` layout which you can use with `Label`s or `Button`s to create calendar view.

Comment: btw: Python has module [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/calendar.html) to genearet calendar in text or HTML but it can also be used to build other generator - `import calendar ; text = calendar.TextCalendar() ; print(text.formatmonth(2017, 12)) ; print(text.formatyear(2017))`

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** I found on SO: [How do I create a date picker in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443786/how-do-i-create-a-date-picker-in-tkinter).

There are widgets for `tkinter` which use `calendar` too

(but if you just need to display events as list then you can need only `Label`/`Button` with `pack()` or  `Listbox`. And this you can find in any tutorial.)

---

`Python` has module [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/calendar.html) which can generate calendar as text or HTML

```
import calendar

text = calendar.TextCalendar() 

print(text.formatmonth(2017, 12))
```

result:

```
   December 2017
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Or for full year

```
print(text.formatyear(2017))
```

result:

```
                                  2017

      January                   February                   March
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                   1             1  2  3  4  5             1  2  3  4  5
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8       6  7  8  9 10 11 12       6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15      13 14 15 16 17 18 19      13 14 15 16 17 18 19
16 17 18 19 20 21 22      20 21 22 23 24 25 26      20 21 22 23 24 25 26
23 24 25 26 27 28 29      27 28                     27 28 29 30 31
30 31

       April                      May                       June
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                1  2       1  2  3  4  5  6  7                1  2  3  4
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9       8  9 10 11 12 13 14       5  6  7  8  9 10 11
10 11 12 13 14 15 16      15 16 17 18 19 20 21      12 13 14 15 16 17 18
17 18 19 20 21 22 23      22 23 24 25 26 27 28      19 20 21 22 23 24 25
24 25 26 27 28 29 30      29 30 31                  26 27 28 29 30

        July                     August                  September
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                1  2          1  2  3  4  5  6                   1  2  3
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9       7  8  9 10 11 12 13       4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10 11 12 13 14 15 16      14 15 16 17 18 19 20      11 12 13 14 15 16 17
17 18 19 20 21 22 23      21 22 23 24 25 26 27      18 19 20 21 22 23 24
24 25 26 27 28 29 30      28 29 30 31               25 26 27 28 29 30
31

      October                   November                  December
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su      Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                   1             1  2  3  4  5                   1  2  3
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8       6  7  8  9 10 11 12       4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15      13 14 15 16 17 18 19      11 12 13 14 15 16 17
16 17 18 19 20 21 22      20 21 22 23 24 25 26      18 19 20 21 22 23 24
23 24 25 26 27 28 29      27 28 29 30               25 26 27 28 29 30 31
30 31
```

It can also gives datetime objects for selected month

```
print(text.monthdatescalendar(2017, 12))
```

Result

```
[[datetime.date(2017, 11, 27), datetime.date(2017, 11, 28), datetime.date(2017, 11, 29), datetime.date(2017, 11, 30), datetime.date(2017, 12, 1), datetime.date(2017, 12, 2), datetime.date(2017, 12, 3)],
 [datetime.date(2017, 12, 4), datetime.date(2017, 12, 5), datetime.date(2017, 12, 6), datetime.date(2017, 12, 7), datetime.date(2017, 12, 8), datetime.date(2017, 12, 9), datetime.date(2017, 12, 10)], 
 [datetime.date(2017, 12, 11), datetime.date(2017, 12, 12), datetime.date(2017, 12, 13), datetime.date(2017, 12, 14), datetime.date(2017, 12, 15), datetime.date(2017, 12, 16), datetime.date(2017, 12, 17)], 
 [datetime.date(2017, 12, 18), datetime.date(2017, 12, 19), datetime.date(2017, 12, 20), datetime.date(2017, 12, 21), datetime.date(2017, 12, 22), datetime.date(2017, 12, 23), datetime.date(2017, 12, 24)], 
 [datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), datetime.date(2017, 12, 26), datetime.date(2017, 12, 27), datetime.date(2017, 12, 28), datetime.date(2017, 12, 29), datetime.date(2017, 12, 30), datetime.date(2017, 12, 31)]]
```

And you can use `Calendar` to create class which generates `tkinter.Frame` like this:

[image]

```
# --- class ---

import calendar
import tkinter

class TkinterCalendar(calendar.Calendar):

    def formatmonth(self, master, year, month):

        dates = self.monthdatescalendar(year, month)

        frame = tkinter.Frame(master)

        self.labels = []

        for r, week in enumerate(dates):
            labels_row = []
            for c, date in enumerate(week):
                label = tkinter.Button(frame, text=date.strftime('%Y\n%m\n%d'))
                label.grid(row=r, column=c)

                if date.month != month:
                    label['bg'] = '#aaa'

                if c == 6:
                    label['fg'] = 'red'

                labels_row.append(label)
            self.labels.append(labels_row)

        return frame


# --- example how to use ---

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tkcalendar = TkinterCalendar()

for year, month in [(2017, 11), (2017, 12), (2018,1)]:
    tk.Label(root, text = '{} / {}'.format(year, month)).pack()

    frame = tkcalendar.formatmonth(root, year, month)
    frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

It still need to display events in calendar and assign function to buttons (every date is `tkinter.Button`).