# Removing 'Week Number' column in Calendar Widget in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, datepicker, tkcalendar

I have a simple Calendar and DateEntry widget from tkcalendar in Python which is working fine and displaying results as attached below.

[image]

I do **not** want it to display the Week Number column in the calendar [or the extra bottom row with the next month's week] - I tried using "*showWeeks = False*" but it does not seem to do the trick.

```
review_date_entry = DateEntry(dates_panel, 
                              textvariable=self.review_date,
                              showWeeks = False)
```

I understand that any customization options for Calendar widget work for DateEntry widget as well therefore any leads will be appreciated, need all the suggestions I can get. Thank you!

Code for Calendar and DateEntry below :

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

def example1():
    def print_sel():
        print(cal.selection_get())

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    cal = Calendar(top,
                   font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',
                   cursor="hand1", year=2018, month=2, day=5)
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()

def example2():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Choose date').pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    cal = DateEntry(top, width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')

ttk.Button(root, text='Calendar', command=example1).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='DateEntry', command=example2).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [tkcalendar](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/releases) now has a `showweeknumbers` option (since version 1.3.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is poor, you have to dig in the [source code](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/blob/master/tkcalendar.py).

The weeks number column corresponds to a list of `wlabel` (instance of `ttk.Label()`) called `_week_nbs`. So you can loop over them and destroy them one after one:

```
for i in range(6):
    cal._week_nbs[i].destroy()
```

**Full program:**

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

def example1():
    def print_sel():
        print(cal.selection_get())

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    cal = Calendar(top,
                   font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',
                   cursor="hand1", year=2018, month=2, day=5)
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    for i in range(6):
       cal._week_nbs[i].destroy()
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()

def example2():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Choose date').pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    cal = DateEntry(top, width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')

ttk.Button(root, text='Calendar', command=example1).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='DateEntry', command=example2).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Hacky but works. I didn't dare recommending to temper with the internal attributes of `Calendar`!

Comment: In fact I must admit this *hack* is against good code practices (manipulating a private attribute) and what you said in your answer is correct. I think the best thing in this situation is to make a function for this purpose and pull request it and hope to be accepted. Nevertheless, what you said in your answer is correct (*it is always added*) +1 @JacquesGaudin

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ : Works like a charm! Although can you explain why the same thing will not work for the DateEntry widget? because as is quoted in multiple places - any option for Calendar should work on DateEntry as well.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work to turn the weeknumbers off:

```
self.de = DateEntry(self.frame, width=12, background='darkblue',
                foreground='white',showweeknumbers=False,firstweekday='sunday')

# To see other parameters that you can change
print("DE keys=",self.de.keys())
```

[Documentation for weeknumbers](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html#tkcalendar.Calendar.__init__)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it doesn't come as an option. In the `__init__` method of `tkcalendar` the [week numbers are always added](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/blob/master/tkcalendar.py#L268), no matter what the options are:

```
    ...
    self._week_nbs = []
    self._calendar = []
    for i in range(1, 7):
        self._cal_frame.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        wlabel = ttk.Label(self._cal_frame, style='headers.%s.TLabel' % self._style_prefixe,
                           font=self._font, padding=2,
                           anchor="e", width=2)
        self._week_nbs.append(wlabel)
        wlabel.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="esnw", padx=(0, 1))
        self._calendar.append([])
        for j in range(1, 8):
            label = ttk.Label(self._cal_frame, style='normal.%s.TLabel' % self._style_prefixe,
                              font=self._font, anchor="center")
            self._calendar[-1].append(label)
            label.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=(0, 1), pady=(0, 1), sticky="nsew")
            if selectmode is "day":
                label.bind("<1>", self._on_click)
```

You may want to try other widgets as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443786/how-do-i-create-a-date-picker-in-tkinter), it seems like [`ttkcalendar`](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/ttk-gsoc/samples/ttkcalendar.py) wouldn't have week numbers.