# Weekly Updating Calendar Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to make a program in python 3.x with tkinter, that will make a calendar appear on the top of the screen that will change every single week. I'm a little lost on where to start (the solution likely incorporates datetime import) but I don't know how to make it update every week. If anyone has any tips on where to start that'd be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443786/how-do-i-create-a-date-picker-in-tkinter

Comment: thanks @Atlas435 but the link provided seems to lead a tkcalendar date picker application; I need to display the week's dates at the top and have the displayed dates change every week.

Comment: You can define a function to check whether current day is changed from `Saturday` to `Sunday` or `Sunday` to `Monday` (depends on what is the first day of week), then update the calendar.  Then use `after()` to call the function periodically.

Comment: as for starter you can get system time with `time` module and then say `time.ctime()` will return the system day and time, u can use the indexing to return the day only, and then check if the day `==` sunday and keep on changing the calendar :D