# Can't load calendar with corresponding date

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkcalendar

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar

def get_date():
    label.configure(text=str(today.get_displayed_month()))
    today.configure(day=str(today.get_date()))

 
win = Tk()
win.title('Calendar Picker')

label = Label(win,text='August 2020')
label.pack(pady=10)

btn = Button(win,text='Pick a date',command=get_date)
btn.pack(pady=10)

today = Calendar(win,selectmode='day',year=2020,month=8,day=6)
today.pack(pady=10)

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Python\Python Projects Fun\calproject.py", line 6, in get_date
    today.configure(day=str(today.get_date()))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tkcalendar\calendar_.py", line 1612, in configure
    self[item] = value
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tkcalendar\calendar_.py", line 518, in __setitem__
    raise AttributeError("Calendar object has no attribute %s." % key)
AttributeError: Calendar object has no attribute day.
```

Sorry when I pressed the button 'Pick a date' then the above error came out. May I ask what should I use if I want the corresponding date shown on top of the window when I move the months? Because I am not clear with the documentations so could someone teach me the method? What is the best way to fix the above error?

Comment: FYI  `today.keys()` returns the list of keywords available in `.configure()`. If you want to change the currently selected day, use `today.selection_set(date)` though I don't understand why you want to set the currently selected date as the selected date. I think acw1668's answer is probably what you are looking for. If you want to ensure that the selected date is visible, then use `today.see(date)`.

Comment: @j_4321 I think what OP wants is that when the month is changed, he wants to highlight the same day as the previous month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because `day` option is only available when you create the `Calendar` instance.  It is not available in `configure()` function.

If you want to update the `label` whenever month is changed, you can bind on `<<CalendarMonthChanged>>` event and update the `label` inside the event callback:

```
def on_month_changed(event):
    month, year = today.get_displayed_month()
    label.configure(text=today._month_names[month]+' '+str(year))

...

today = Calendar(win, selectmode='day', year=2020, month=8, day=6)
today.pack(pady=10)
today.bind('<<CalendarMonthChanged>>', on_month_changed)
```

---

*UPDATE:* If you want to select the same day after the month is changed, modify the `get_date()` function as below:

```
import calendar
...
def get_date():
    month, year = today.get_displayed_month()
    # get the last day of selected month
    _, lastday = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
    # make sure day is valid day in selected month
    day = min(today._sel_date.day, lastday)
    # select the day in selected month
    today.selection_set(today.date(year, month, day))
```

---

*UPDATE 2:* Below is an example to update the calendar when a date is selected via `tkcalendar.DateEntry`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

def date_selected(event):
    date = date_entry.get_date()
    cal.selection_set(date)
 
win = Tk()
win.title('Calendar Picker')

date_entry = DateEntry(win, date_pattern='y-mm-dd', state='readonly')
date_entry.pack()
date_entry.bind('<<DateEntrySelected>>', date_selected)

cal = Calendar(win, selectmode='day', date_pattern='y-mm-dd')
cal.pack(pady=10)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would like to have a button for picking selected date and go to the corresponding date so what should I use?

Comment: It said calendar is not defined after I changed

Comment: Did you add the line `import calendar` as in my updated code?

Comment: ```_, lastday = calendar.monthrange(year, month)``` what does this mean?

Comment: `monthrange(year, month)` returns *weekday of first day of the month* and *number of days in month*, for the *specified year and month*.

Comment: I may want to do the effect that when I click button can choose specific date then going to the corresponding month and highlight the specific date so how should I change ?

Comment: After I select the specific date why the calendar doesn't go to the specific month?

Comment: It works fine in my Python 3 in Windows 10.

Comment: Any button after I selected from entrybox?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: For example the entry will have the calendar months to select dates but after click then the below calendar still remain unchanged

Comment: Now default is August but when I select a date from October it still remains at August

Comment: As I said it works fine in my Python environment.  The calendar is changed to whatever selected in the date entry.

Comment: It works fine now after I used the updated ones Thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your question.

Comment: Click which button to accept?

Comment: Click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons.