# Show current date in the calander

Tags: python, tkinter

Show current date in the calander

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

date_field = DateEntry(root, selectmode="day", year=2021, month=12, day=8)
date_field.grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx="100")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have completely changed the question.  Better post another question instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a date picker in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443786/how-do-i-create-a-date-picker-in-tkinter)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because The question was changed after answers were posted

Comment: It seams to me that someone wants all the answers with no effort at all. Please close this question.

Answer (score 2):

One of the way:

```py
...
timeslots = [f'{hr:02}:{mi:02}' for hr in range(24) for mi in range(0, 60, 15)]
kommt_field = ttk.Combobox(root, values=timeslots)
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

date_field = DateEntry(root, selectmode="day"8)
date_field.grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx="100")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no need to make a self-answer question because this thing has been asked a lot of times. First, check if the question is a duplicate before posting.

Comment: Also, please remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach to your original question?